# Is it possible to display email tracking information on a microsite by amscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, data, microsites

Is it possible to display email tracking information on a microsite by amscript?

I would like to display email tracking information for all the emails sent to XYZ data extension.

So, display email name (or subjects) of all the emails sent to XYZ data extension.

Is it feasible by amscript on a microsite?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do it because even in the data views the DE Send is stored against the ListID of all subscribers. It doesn't have the DE External Key. So finding the sends to a specific DE is not something that I have seen

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think is to have have Send Logging enabled and to include whatever data you'd like (maybe even DE name) to bridge the internal data views to those sent in a particular DE.